# Editar Registro Usando Jpa

Tags: java, jpa

Bom dia

Pessoal,

estou Tentando editar registro.

bom a cenário é o seguinte tenho minha tela editar que está me trazendo os dados Corretamente.

porem quando eu faço a edição ele atualiza na tela mais no banco não.

tenho as seguintes tabelas conforme abaixo.

**tabela = pessoa**      como as seguintes propriedade id,nome

**tabela = funcionário** como as seguintes propriedade id,cargo e id_pessoa(fk)

tenho Minhas classes Repositorios Conforme abaixo para cada entity ou seja pessoa e Funcionario

```
package br.com.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.model.FuncionarioModel;


public class FuncionarioRepository implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Inject
    public FuncionarioRepository(EntityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public FuncionarioModel porId(Long id) {
        return manager.find(FuncionarioModel.class, id);
    }

    public List<FuncionarioModel> todos() {
        TypedQuery<FuncionarioModel> query = manager.createQuery("from FuncionarioModel", FuncionarioModel.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public FuncionarioModel guardar(FuncionarioModel funcionario) {
        return this.manager.merge(funcionario);
    }

    public void remover(FuncionarioModel funcionario) {
        this.manager.remove(funcionario);
    }

    public List<String> cargosQueContem(String cargo) {
        TypedQuery<String> query = manager.createQuery(
                "select distinct cargo from Funcionario " + "where upper(cargo) like upper(:cargo)",
                String.class);
        query.setParameter("cargo", "%" + cargo + "%");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

```
package br.com.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.model.PessoaModel;


public class PessoaRepository implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Inject
    public PessoaRepository(EntityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public PessoaModel porId(Long id) {
        return manager.find(PessoaModel.class, id);
    }

    public List<PessoaModel> todas() {
        TypedQuery<PessoaModel> query = manager.createQuery("from PessoaModel", PessoaModel.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public PessoaModel guardar(PessoaModel pessoa) {
        return this.manager.merge(pessoa);
    }

    public void remover(PessoaModel pessoa) {
        this.manager.remove(pessoa);
    }

    public List<String> nomesQueContem(String nome) {
        TypedQuery<String> query = manager.createQuery(
                "select distinct nome from Pessoa " + "where upper(nome) like upper(:nome)",
                String.class);
        query.setParameter("nome", "%" + nome + "%");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

e minhas classes controller conforme abaixo

```
package br.com.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.model.PessoaModel;
import br.com.repository.PessoaRepository;
import br.com.util.NegocioException;
import br.com.util.Transactional;

public class PessoaController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @Transactional
    public PessoaModel salvar(PessoaModel pessoaModel) throws NegocioException {
        if (pessoaModel.getNome().isEmpty()) {
            throw new NegocioException("Nome da Pessoa Não pode ser vazio ");
        }
        return this.pessoaRepository.guardar(pessoaModel);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void excluir(PessoaModel pessoaModel) throws NegocioException {
        pessoaModel = this.pessoaRepository.porId(pessoaModel.getCodigo());
        if (pessoaModel.getNome() == null) {
            throw new NegocioException("Não é possível excluir um Funcionario Demitido!");
        }
        this.pessoaRepository.remover(pessoaModel);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void atualizar(PessoaModel pessoaModel) throws NegocioException {
        pessoaModel = this.pessoaRepository.porId(pessoaModel.getCodigo());
    }

}
```

```
package br.com.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.model.FuncionarioModel;
import br.com.repository.FuncionarioRepository;
import br.com.util.NegocioException;
import br.com.util.Transactional;

public class FuncionarioController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private FuncionarioRepository funcionarioRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void salvar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
        if (funcionarioModel.getCargo().isEmpty() ) {
            throw new NegocioException("Não é Possivel Salvar Funcionario sem Cargo");
        }
        this.funcionarioRepository.guardar(funcionarioModel);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void excluir(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
        funcionarioModel = this.funcionarioRepository.porId(funcionarioModel.getCodigo());
        if (funcionarioModel.getCargo()== null) {
            throw new NegocioException("Não é possível excluir um Funcionario Demitido!");
        }
        this.funcionarioRepository.remover(funcionarioModel);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void atualizar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
        funcionarioModel = this.funcionarioRepository.porId(funcionarioModel.getCodigo());
    }


}
```

e por Ultimo minha classe Bean

```
package br.com.view;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import br.com.controller.FuncionarioController;
import br.com.controller.PessoaController;
import br.com.model.FuncionarioModel;
import br.com.model.PessoaModel;
import br.com.repository.FuncionarioRepository;
import br.com.util.NegocioException;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ConsultaFuncionariosBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private FuncionarioController funcionarioController;

    @Inject
    private PessoaController pessoaController;

    @Inject transient
    private FuncionarioRepository funcionarioRepository;

    @Produces
    private List<FuncionarioModel> funcionarios;

    @Inject transient
    private FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel;

    @Inject transient
    private PessoaModel pessoaModel;


    @PostConstruct
    public void consultar() {
        this.funcionarios = funcionarioRepository.todos();
    }

    public void Excluir(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException{
        this.funcionarioController.excluir(funcionarioModel);
        this.pessoaController.excluir(funcionarioModel.getPessoaModel());
        //Atualiza o Registro na Tela Assim que For Excluído
        this.consultar();
    }

    //Carrega as Informações de Um funcionario para ser Editada.
    public void Editar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException{
        this.funcionarioModel = funcionarioModel;
    }

    //Atualiza Registro Alterado
    public void AlterarRegistro() throws NegocioException{
        this.funcionarioController.atualizar(funcionarioModel);
        this.pessoaController.atualizar(funcionarioModel.getPessoaModel());
    }

    public List<FuncionarioModel> getFuncionarios() {
        return funcionarios;
    }

    public void setFuncionarios(List<FuncionarioModel> funcionarios) {
        this.funcionarios = funcionarios;
    }

    public FuncionarioModel getFuncionarioModel() {
        return funcionarioModel;
    }

    public void setFuncionarioModel(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) {
        this.funcionarioModel = funcionarioModel;
    }

}
```

Caso alguém já passou por isso ou saiba como posso resolver fico grato

pessoal descobri que apos eu achar o objeto pelo find do marge ele estava retornado no meu get o resultado do banco não do formulário, resolvi da seguinte  forma criei uma variável guardei o resultado do formulário conforme abaixo, mais achei que não é a solução mais correta se alguem poder me corrigir.

```
    @Transactional
public void atualizar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
    String cargo = funcionarioModel.getCargo(); 
    funcionarioModel = this.funcionarioRepository.porId(funcionarioModel.getCodigo());
    funcionarioModel.setCargo(cargo);

}
```

Comment: Selecionar o código e clicar **Ctrl + K** ou clicar no botão de formatação, faz com que ele fique bem formatado =)

Comment: Não lembro se é o `merge` ou o `update`, mas tem um deles que você tem que fazer `.flush()` (algo alguma coisa parecida).

Comment: Valeu Igor por responder, você não teria um exemplo de como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: na verdade eu gostaria de usar os metodos get  e set das minhas entity ou seja pegar o dados que foram alterados no formulário conforme exemplo =  pessoaEntity.setNome(pessoaModel.getNome()) , assim seria uma maneira  mais correta de tratar o objeto, mais quando faço assim ele retorna os dados do banco e não o do formulário alterado.

Comment: É só fazer `seuEntityManager.flush()` logo depois do `.merge(T)`. Vi que você está usando o `merge` em métodos chamado `guarda`. Se você quer adicionar um registro você deve usar `.persist(T)`. O `merge` e `update` servem apenas para atualizar informações já existentes no banco.

Answer (score 0):

O comando **merge** serve para tornar a entidade gerenciável pelo seu *EntityManager*, porém se você quer salvar as alterações da entidade no banco, você deve chamar o método ***flush()***, ou até mesmo abrir e fechar uma transação, o que também faz o serviço embora o primeiro método seja mais rápido.

```
public PessoaModel guardar(PessoaModel pessoa) {
    return this.manager.merge(pessoa);
}
```

Esse trecho acima só faz com que a entidade esteja em modo "gerenciável" pelo EntityManager, chame o método **manager.flush();** para salvar os dados no banco.

```
public PessoaModel guardar(PessoaModel pessoa) {
    this.manager.merge(pessoa);
    this.manager.flush();
    return pessoa;
}
```